# In cocos2dx Http Gzip Request is not working

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-x

I'm a `cocos2dx` developer. In this code, server throws error, your data is not a `GZIP` format. help me on how to convert Gzip Format !

```
void HelloWorld::requestToserver()
{

    string postData ="client side request";
    // Setting HTTP Request Header
    std::vector<std::string> headers;
    vector<string> pHeraders;
    pHeraders.push_back("Accept-Encoding:gzip");
    pHeraders.push_back("Content-Type:application/json");
    pHeraders.push_back("Content-Encoding:gzip");

    // Creating a URL
    cocos2d::extension::CCHttpRequest * request = new cocos2d::extension::CCHttpRequest();
    request->setUrl("http://192.168.1.47:8080/PicL…/PlayerRecordClientInteraction");

    // If you want to use GET method, replace kHttpPost to kHttpGet
    request->setRequestType(cocos2d::extension::CCHttpRequest::kHttpPost);
    request->setResponseCallback(this, httpresponse_selector(HelloWorld::onHttpRequestCompleted));
    request->setRequestData(postData, strlen(postData));
    request->setHeaders(headers);
    request->setTag("POST Request");

    // Execute
    cocos2d::extension::CCHttpClient::getInstance()->send(request);

    // Release the Connection
    request->release();   
}

void DailyPuzzle::onHttpRequestCompleted(cocos2d::CCNode * sender, void * data)
{
    HttpResponse * response = (HttpResponse *)data;
    if (!response)
    {
    return;
    }
    if (0 != strlen(response->getHttpRequest()->getTag()))
    {
    CCLog("%s completed", response->getHttpRequest()->getTag());
    }

    // Check the HTTP Status Code
    int statusCode = response->getResponseCode();
    char statusString[64] = {};
    sprintf(statusString, "HTTP Status Code: %d, tag = %s", statusCode, response->getHttpRequest()->getTag());
    CCLog("response code: %d", statusCode);

    // A connection failure
    if (!response->isSucceed())
    {
    CCLog("response failed");
    CCLog("error buffer: %s", response->getErrorBuffer());
    return;
    }

    // The data will be placed in the buffer.
    std::vector<char> * buffer = response->getResponseData();
    char * concatenated = (char *) malloc(buffer->size() + 1);
    std::string s2(buffer->begin(), buffer->end());
    strcpy(concatenated, s2.c_str());

}
```